# how to display a image from google driver with paperclip-googledrive in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, google-drive-api

i want to display a image from a public folder in Google driver, when i get url a image

```
Product.first.image.url
#=> ArgumentError: Missing access token.
```

I think it didn't get google drive path.

Product Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image,
                    :storage => :google_drive,
                    :google_drive_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/google_driver.yml",
                    :styles => { :medium => "300x300", :thumb => "100x100", :large => "800x600" },
                    :google_drive_options => {
                    :path => proc { |style| "#{style}_#{id}_#{image.original_filename}" },
                      :public_folder_id => '0B0VNyOkzIwUZQjFRU2NUX3pYSGs'
                    }
  end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't know so much about ruby, but I know about google drive.
So, you are trying to read the file, but you need first the access token. Maybe you need to read about how to [Retrieve and Use OAuth 2.0 Credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/credentials), there you have a basic example with Ruby.

Once you have the credentials, you need to do a query searching for your file or try to read the file. [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) you can read about it.

Finally, once you have your image file, maybe the property you are looking for is the webContentLink. I was able to display the picture in a web Browser.